# simple istream_iterator question

Tags: c++, copy, istream-iterator

I am new to C++, sorry if this is a silly question. I cannot seem to figure out why this does not work. It copies into the first vector, and seems to skip past the second copy call.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<int> first;
    vector<int> second;

    copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin),istream_iterator<int>(),back_inserter(first));
    cin.clear();
    copy(istream_iterator<int>(cin),istream_iterator<int>(),back_inserter(second)); 
    return 0;
}
```

I want to use the copy function to read istream_iterator input into any number of vectors(one call to copy per vector). In other words: I want to be able to enter "1 2 3 4 5 ctrl+d" into the console and have 1,2,3,4,5 entered into the first vector. Then enter "6 7 8 9 10 ctrl+d" into the console and have 6,7,8,9,10 entered into the second vector.

The problem is that after I enter some input into the first vector and press control+d the istream_iterator for cin remains equal to istream_iterator(), regardless of cin's fail state. This causes every subsequent call to "copy" to fail (because istream_iteratorcin is already equal to istream_iterator() which the program interprets as eof). 
So my question is: What do I need to do to "reset" the iterator along with the cin stream? cin.clear() is indeed clearing all the fail bits. However the istream_iterator(cin) is still equal to istream_iterator() regardless. From what I understand, istream_iterators that are bound to a stream should only be equal to the default istream_iterator value when the stream is in a fail state. What am I missing?

Comment: Define `How it should work` and `what is not working`.

Comment: I am trying to enter some numbers into stdin and have those ints copied into the first vector until I press ctrl-d at which point the first copy will stop. Then I want to clear the fail state of stdin and repeat the process of copying numbers into the second vector. The problem is that it copies into the first but does not copy into the second because somehow the istream_iterator<int>(cin) remains equal to istream_iterator<int>(). I thought that clearing the fail state and recalling istream_iterator<int>(cin) would give me fresh iterator that is not equal to the default istream_iterator value.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my end. I input the first set of values, ^D, input the second set of values, ^D, program terminates with correct ouput (I'm dumping the vector elements to check).

Comment: Luc, really?? You are using the exact same code and it works for you??

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/vLReO) is what my program looks like and what I input (with a ^D after each line). Ideone only pass the whole of input in one go so it all ends up in the first vector and is not representative of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `istream_iterator` is an *input iterator*, which means you can only dereference each iterator value *once*. You are literally reading from a stream, and there's no seeking or going back. So once you hit the end-of-stream, there's nothing more to input and the second range is empty.

Why not just say `vector<int> second(first);` to make a copy?

---

Update: After you clarified the question, here's a new answer: You're misunderstanding how `stdin` works. There is only *one* input. `Ctrl-D` isn't anything inherent to C++; rather, it is a convention of your platform, and your platform will terminate the input buffer when you signal `Ctrl-D`. After that, the input "file" is finished, and no further data can be written to it.

Your approach is a bit unorthodox, though. Usually, you would just read line by line, separated by `Enter`, and tokenize each line. Using string streams, you get very similar code:

```
std::string line;
std::vector<int> first, second;

// Read line 1
if (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(first));
}
else { /* error */ }

// Read line 2
if (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(second));
}
else { /* error */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I do realize there are much easier ways to make the copy, I'm just trying to better understand how istream_iterators work. So if I am understanding correctly, once I hit control+d while reading input with the istream_iterator, the iterator becomes essentially useless beyond that point? Is there no way to "reset" or "re-instantiate" the iterator so that I can read from it again?

Comment: @Kaleetos: At the heart, it's the same as reading from `stdin`. You can't go back. Once you read data, it's gone from the input buffer.

Comment: fair enough, but then is there some other technique whereby I can use the istream_iterator<T>(stream) again later? perhaps should I use my own terminator value rather than using the default istream_iterator value? It just seems strange to me because this particular method of copying input into a string is a common example I've found on many sites (and in the book I'm reading). So it seems strange to me that there would be no mention of the fact that once this method is used once in program it can't be used again.

Comment: @Kaleetos: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. If you want some other sort of data source, don't use `cin`... Maybe update your question to explain precisely what you goal and problems are.

Comment: I updated the question Kerrek. I think I may have mislead you when I responded to your first answer saying that "I know there are easier ways to make a copy." I am not actually trying to make a copy of vectors-- but rather trying to use the copy function to read stdin input values into multiple vectors (via istream_iterators). I hope the edited question above better explains it!

Comment: @Kaleetos: I know that you were using `copy` to read input. That much is fine and well. I just don't understand what you *mean* by reading from the input twice. (Your update explains it better, though, but I have to think about it. I don't think you can do it that way, but I'm not 100% sure.)

Comment: @Kaleetos: I updated the answer, perhaps you'll find this useful.

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you Kerrek, you nailed the explanation and the solution.